# Probit and heckit first stage produce (slightly) different results

Tags: r, non-linear-regression

I am runnig a Heckman sample selection (2-step) model to model farmer's participation (and participation intensity) in some conservation schemes using the 'heckit' command from the package 'sampleSelection'.

For comparison, I also modelled the first step as a Probit, as from my understanding this should give identical results to the first stage of the Heckit. The estimates are indeed identical, but standard errors are not (although they are quite close). In the example below this doesn't matter much, but in my actual case it has an impact on significance levels, so I would like to understand where the difference comes from. Does anyone have an idea?

Here is an example:

```
library(sampleSelection)
data("Mroz87", package = "sampleSelection")

heck1 = heckit( lfp ~ age + I( age^2 ) + kids5 + huswage + educ,
               log(wage) ~ educ + exper + I( exper^2 ) + city, data=Mroz87)

prob1 <- glm(lfp ~ age + I( age^2 ) + kids5 + huswage + educ, 
             family=binomial(link='probit'), data=Mroz87)
summary(prob1)
summary(heck1)
```

The SEs are almost but not fully identical:

```
Probit coefficients:
Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -0.6204200  1.5062525  -0.412 0.680415    
age          0.0100365  0.0685764   0.146 0.883641    
I(age^2)    -0.0004891  0.0007796  -0.627 0.530364    
kids5       -0.8546564  0.1156353  -7.391 1.46e-13 ***
huswage     -0.0421711  0.0122853  -3.433 0.000598 ***
educ         0.1476737  0.0235001   6.284 3.30e-10 ***

Heckit coefficients:
Probit selection equation:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -0.6204199  1.5164452  -0.409 0.682564    
age          0.0100365  0.0689931   0.145 0.884378    
I(age^2)    -0.0004891  0.0007841  -0.624 0.532954    
kids5       -0.8546564  0.1153682  -7.408  3.5e-13 ***
huswage     -0.0421711  0.0124158  -3.397 0.000719 ***
educ         0.1476737  0.0234280   6.303  5.0e-10 ***
Outcome equation:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -0.5471531  0.2890638  -1.893  0.05877 .  
educ         0.1064521  0.0171745   6.198 9.48e-10 ***
exper        0.0411569  0.0131805   3.123  0.00186 ** 
I(exper^2)  -0.0008014  0.0003950  -2.029  0.04282 *  
city         0.0532725  0.0687956   0.774  0.43897
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO ! I think your question would have a better chance at an answer on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com), SO's statistics counterpart.

Comment: I generally agree that Cross Validated might be better suited, which is why I have now flagged the post for moderator attention and asked for migration. 
However, I guess one likely option why the results may be different is that the packages are programmed differently, so in case anyone would know about that over here I'd be grateful for a hint whether (and how) this is the case.